# How to create private security certificates that behave like official ones?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, openssl

I'm trying to get a valid secured environment for HTTP communication to behave like normal ones. I'm doing this for a restricted group of users.
There is a hardware server running a web service (nginx). OpenSSL is installed on this machine and I'm using it as a CA as well. I have created the root CA certificate and I have signed a certificate for the web service using it. Then I have provided the root CA certificate to a *trusted user* (another PC controlled by me) and it was imported to Firefox as a trusted authority.
Almost everything works fine (the HTTPS service is accessible and the *warning* page doesn't appear), but I get a *blue* status (the first thing in the address bar, before https://... ) of the service stating:

```
Youy are connected to
example.com
which is run by
(unknown)
Verified by: MyCA Company
```

Other world-wide known HTTPS sites like addons.mozilla.com, for example, show a *green* status and they don't have this **(unknown)** piece of data. They have there the company name and location.

Is it possible to get a custom private secured environemt behave like a normal one and be *green*? If yes, what should be done in order to get this (client-side? server-side?) ?

As a side-effect question: where could I learn about PKI, SSL, an all this stuff *from 0 to advanced*? or maybe there are some good books related to this?

Thank you in advance for any help and answers.

Comment: My guess is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) is missing, or the browser is not set up to trust the CA.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Yes, I think this is the correct direction of research for this question. The browser has the root CA certificate imported and it doesn't show a warning page when accessing the site, so it should be OK. Thank you for your note, it is useful. Still waiting for a more practical solution using *openssl* tools (if it exists).

Comment: [Related](http://serverfault.com/questions/48053/can-i-build-my-own-extended-validation-ssl-certificate).

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Thanks. Basically this related thread on serverfault.com answered the question, only some datails remained: is it possible to get a custom *company name* and *country* like "Mozilla Corporation (US)" for a *blue* (not EV) certified site? or the color and this data is strictly related? (not asking especially you, maybe someone else will read this and could answer too)

Comment: [I don't think so](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#User_interface). But I have no experience with SSL certificates — just wait a bit for a more qualified answer.

Comment: It is impossible to add a CA to the Software Security Device (the place where you install your own root CA certificate) and mark it as able to issue EV certificates. If you need the green bar, you'll have to download NSS and create your own version with your root CA installed and marked as EV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't—that's pretty much the reasoning behind the EV certificates (those that make the location bar go green). You'd practically have to patch your browser or hack some EV-CAs private key.

I've found a thread on the [OpenSSL mailing list](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/extended-validation-certificates-td23575.html) that explains the problem; you might also want to look at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_validation) about what all this extended validation stuff is.

As for your side question: The whole PKI and SSL stuff is hideously complex. I've found an [article](http://www.homeworks.it/Html/OpenSSL_PKI_Articolo_Eng.html) that explains some of the theory behind building your own PKI, but this is far from being a nice "from zero to advanced" tutorial. Then there is of course [RFC 5280](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt), but this makes for some *very* heavy reading. But at least it's the official standard, for what it's worth.